# Application manager for microservices

Tags: microservices

I'm trying to migrate some apps from a web container into microservices with Spring Boot.

My question is, is there any application manager out there which looks like Systemd or other programing-language-agnostic managers which can manage all my applications?

I don't like Systemd, because it requires Linux admin to start stop applications.

FYI, I'm not using Docker for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a lot of details about your setup (except not using docker) -so the answer is also quite generic. It does seem, however, you can benefit from Mesos (or its more user friendly incarnation DC/OS)

Comment: I think my details is enough already. I need something like systemd or init.d alike to start my application either Java, Python, etc without root access required.